# Need to subtract value of one column from all others; Can't figure out mistake in this line?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, data-manipulation, col

I need to take columns 3 to 14-1 and subtract value of column 14 from all of these:

labdata_snus_var[,3:ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1] <- labdata_snus_var[,14] - labdata_snus_var[,3:ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put () around ncol(...)-1.

```
labdata_snus_var[,3:(ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1)] <- labdata_snus_var[,14] - labdata_snus_var[,3:(ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1)]
```

In your example 3:ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1 you get a vector from 3 to 14 and each value will be decreased by one. The result is a vector from 2 to 13.
The brackets around (ncol(labdata_snus_var)-1) means you substract one just from ncol(labdata_snus_var). So you get a vector from 3 to 13.

Comment: thanks @tamtam I would have never found this out; almost like 'C' and not 'R' ;-)

Comment: I want to appreciate the help provided by all above users in this thread and the stackoverflow community for your assistance in visualization of data in one of my upcoming publications. Kindly contact me if you do not consent to using your user ID in the acknowledgements. Thank you and all the best! Stay safe and healthy!!